# Pass a delegate as a type paramater into a method

Tags: c#, delegates

How would one make a method would take a Method info and create a delegate of a certain type (like `Action`) from it? It's kind of a pain to have something like  `Action foo = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), info)` in my code every-time I want to do this, especially if the Delegate type in question is something like `Func<String, String, String, String, String, String>`

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: See aside on the answer.

Comment: I get that, and it's nice that you're willing to share this with the community.  But for the answer to have value, the question needs to be properly expressed.

Comment: Ok, I was mostly not wanting to do something like this:  `Action foo = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), info)`

Comment: A lot of people frown upon asking your own questions and answering them here on stackoverflow, no idea why, but they do. Also, what's to stop you from doing quite simply "delegate{your code here} in the parameter and then using the Action class as the actual parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can call `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, it returns an object of the type of `Delegate`. But I was able to make such a method that returns with the type you provide. It looks like this:

```
public static T MakeDelegate<T>(MethodInfo info){
    return (T)(Object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), info);
}
```

and invoke it like this:

```
Action foo = MakeDelegate<Action>(bar);
```

I have tested it, and it does work.

Aside: I was looking for a question to attach this answer to, but couldn't find one, so I made one.

Comment: And with `var foo = MakeDelegate<Action>(bar);` you only need to write the type once instead of twice.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet The use of var leads to convoluted "vomit-speak" coding. Explicit declaration is the recommended standard. Type it twice once, so the guy after you doesn't need to read it four times.

Comment: @Krythic: That's debatable. `var` can definitively make code harder to understand and it's worth pointing that out. But in this case, it removes a *duplicate* type annotation, which - in my opinion - makes it more readable (and it's what the OP is all about). Now you could argue that `MakeDelegate<Action>()` doesn't necessarily return an `Action` and that you'd have to double-check that, but you'd probably have to look at that method anyway to fully understand the code.